# Replace outlers with NA in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, na, outliers

Given a numpy array like this

```
[[100, 110, 0.01, 110], [120, 100, 112, 100], [4000, 100, 200, 100]]
```

How can I replace the outliers with NA?

```
[[100, 110, NA, 110], [120, 100, 112, 100], [NA, 100, 200, 100]]
```

As for outlier detection, I'm happy with 2 SD's from the mean

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what you've tried so far, ie. some kind of function that loops through the array elements? This is too minimal at the moment to give meaningful help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you have a SD and mean functions coded or imported somewhere.

So you should code like this:

```
sd = my_sd_function(my_array)
mean = my_mean_function(my_array)
outliers = (my_array > (mean + 2 * sd)) | (my_array < (mean - 2 * sd))
my_array[outliers] = NA
```

But consider:

- Seriously, I don't know what do you mean by NA. Perhaps `None`?
- I don't understand the structure of your array to make the appropriate functions. Perhaps these functions could satisfy your needs?:

  ```
  def my_mean_function(arr):
      return arr.sum() / arr.size

  def my_sd_function(arr):
      mean = my_mean_function(arr)
      sqrerr = ((arr - mean) ** 2).sum() / arr.size
      return sqrt(sqrerr)
  ```

The core part here you should know is to actually select and update array elements based on a condition you want.

Here, you will use `&` `~` and `|` instead of `and` `not` and `or` keywords. That is because numpy arrays have somehow defined their implementations to make use of such operators (and language constructors `and` `or` and `not` are not actually operators that one can overload).

Such constructs return objects that can be threated like arrays (you can print `outliers` in console / ipython and see what I am talking about).

The second part is that you can pass to `my_array[...]` as an index, actually a list of indexes or constructs like that (e.g. slices) and retrieve / alter such elements in an efficient way (IIRC such approach creates something called *view* to that data in the underlying origin data blob in the numpy array).

Comment: Yes - None is what I was looking for as opposed to NA. It gives me a nan which I can use to filter out outliers